# Comparing Query Results to List Difference in Results of Queries

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to determine which students do not have a textbook checked out for a specific course. I am using MariaDB

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `AllRosters2324`
WHERE `Teacher` = 'TeacherName' AND `Period` IN (2,6)
```

Returns 66 students on the roster for this course across two periods.

Next,

```
SELECT `Title`, `Patron Barcode`
FROM `textBooks`
WHERE `Title` = "TextBookTitle" AND 
`Patron Barcode` IN (
SELECT `Student-ID` AS "Patron Barcode"
FROM `AllRosters2324`
WHERE `Teacher` = 'TeacherName' AND `Period` IN (2,6))
```

Returns a list of students in those periods that have the text assigned. In this case the number on the list is 57. Therefore 9 students do not have the text assigned.

```
SELECT `Student-ID`
FROM `AllRosters2223`
WHERE `Teacher` = 'TeacherName' AND `Period` IN (2,6)
```

Returns the IDs of the 66 students enrolled across the periods.

How can I write a query to list those 9 students IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a left (outer) join between the students table and the text book table, you can determine which students have no link (and therefore have not checked out the relevant book):

```
SELECT `Student - ID`
FROM `AllRosters2223` r
LEFT JOIN `textBooks` t ON t.`Title` = 'TextBookTitle'
    AND t.`Patron Barcode` = r.`Student - ID`
WHERE r.`Teacher` = 'TeacherName'
    AND r.`Period` IN (2, 6)
    AND t.`Patron Barcode` IS NULL
```

The outer join allows all rows of the student table to exist in the result, so when there is no link into the text book table any column referring to that table will be null. This is exploited in the where clause to find the delinquent students.

note the use of table aliases (r = roster, t = textbook)